# Rootscope for Modules in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

Does having multiple modules in an angular app means there are multiple `$rootScope`?

If yes, how can we communicate between multiple `$rootScopes`?

Comment: there is only ever one `$rootScope` in an angular application.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one $rootScope. Communication between child scopes is handled by $emit and $broadcast.

**$rootScope**

Every application has a single root scope. All other scopes are descendant scopes of the root scope. Scopes provide separation between the model and the view, via a mechanism for watching the model for changes.

**$emit**

Dispatches an event name upwards through the scope hierarchy notifying the registered $rootScope.

**$broadcast**

Dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children) notifying the registered $rootScope.

**Source:**
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope